# How to get data from multiple child component in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I was having a parent component named `Cart.jsx` in react and the child component named `Card.jsx`.

The Parent component looks like this.

**Cart.jsx**

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Card from "../../Components/Card";

function Cart() {
   const cart = [**Array of Objects**]
   const [total,setTotal] = useState([]);

      return (
        <div className="cart__Items">
           <Card item={cart[0]} />;
           <Card item={cart[1]} />;
           <Card item={cart[2]} />;
        </div>
      )
}

export default Cart;
```

And the Card Component looks as follows

**Card.jsx**

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Card() {
   const [price,setPrice] = useState(0);
    
   // in-between implemented some function to calculate price value.

      return (
        <div>
         // rendering code 
        </div>
      )
}

export default Card;
```

Now the problem is, how do I get the `price` data of each child component and store them in the `total` array of the parent component.

Here the parent has 3 `Card`components, I need to get the `price` data from each component and store them in the `Cart` component

Comment: If `cart object` has price. Inside `Card` you can simply fetch via `item.price`

Comment: I need to pass data from child to parent, in my case I need 3 ```price``` values from 3 child components to be stored in parent. @ShubhamVerma

Comment: can you add an example of your data `[**Array of Objects**]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the code. I hope this might help

```
 import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
 import Card from "../../Components/Card";

 function Cart() {
  const cart = [**Array of Objects**]
  const [total,setTotal] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div className="cart__Items">
       {cart.map(crt =><Card item={crt} total={total} setTotal={setTotal} />}
    </div>
  )
}

export default Cart;


import React, { useState } from "react";

function Card(props) {
   const [price,setPrice] = useState(0);
   const {setTotal, total} = props
   useEffect(()=>{
      setTotal(total+price)
   },[])
   // in-between implemented some function to calculate price value.

  return (
    <div>
     // rendering code 
    </div>
  )
}

export default Card;
```

Answer (score 0):

````
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Card from "../../Components/Card";

function Cart() {
   const cart = [**Array of Objects**]
   const [total,setTotal] = useState([]);

      return (
        <div className="cart__Items">
           {cart.map((item) => (<Card item={item} setTotal={setTotal} />))}
        </div>
      )
}
export default Cart;```

Now you have access to the setTotal function inside each card Item from which you can update the parent state of "total".
````

Answer (score 0):

If you feel like the individual prices are to be calculated by the child you should use an event handler prop :

Cart.jsx

```
import React, { useState, useEffect, useContext } from "react";
import Card from "../../Components/Card";

function Cart() {
   const cart = [**Array of Objects**]
   const [total,setTotal] = useState(0);

   const handlePriceCalculated = price => {
      setTotal(total + price);
   }

   return (
      <div className="cart__Items">
         <Card item={cart[0]} onPriceCalculated={handlePriceCalculated} />
         <Card item={cart[1]} onPriceCalculated={handlePriceCalculated} />
         <Card item={cart[2]} onPriceCalculated={handlePriceCalculated} />
      </div>
   )
}

export default Cart;
```

Card.jsx

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

function Card({
   onPriceCalculated
}) {
   const [price,setPrice] = useState(0);
    
   // in-between implemented some function to calculate price value.
      ...
      setPrice(calculatedValue)
      onPriceCalculated(calculatedValue)
      ...

   return (
      <div>
         // rendering code 
      </div>
   )
}

export default Card;
```

Giving the responsability to the child to set the total is a bad practise and will result in your components not to be reusable as they would be too hardly coupled.